# If I replace an image in a PictureBox control, should I dispose the original image first?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, idisposable

Following on from [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548664/long-overdue-for-me-question-about-disposing-managed-objects-in-net-vb-net), if I replace an image in a picture box, should I dispose the original image first?

Or, what about this situation:

```
Dim bm As New Bitmap(32,32)  
bm = New Bitmap(32,32)  
bm = New Bitmap(32,32)  
bm = New Bitmap(32,32)
```

Does `bm` need only to be disposed at the end, or should it be disposed before each re-creation?

---

Thanks all for the answers. A big oversight there on my part. I knew a control took care of disposing its children but It hadn't occurred to me that I should dispose an old image if I replaced it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should dispose the old object before you create a new image on top of the same variable.  By creating a new image with the same variable, you are removing a reference to it.  If there are no references to the old object, you are signifying that it should be picked up by the GC (Garbage Collector).  Although technically, this "should" eventually result in the memory being freed assuming that the finalizer makes sure that non-managed resources are taken care of, this is a big assumption (You can't even really assume that the finalizer will be called), and it causes more work for the system. Non-default finalizers causes extra work for the GC in terms of garbage collection level promotion, resulting in taking longer for the memory to be deallocated, and the number of times the GC has to run to do so.

This is assuming that is all written to make sure the finalizer handles it.  Anytime an object has a Dispose method (anything which implements IDisposable which BitMap does), it should be called before removing reference to the object (falling out of scope, removing reference to the object etc.).

Here is an article on how the Garbage Collector works in .net

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33167

Here is how MS says the dispose / finalizer should be implemented:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx

Answer (score 4):

When changing the image associated with a `PictureBox`, one should call `Dispose` on the image that was there if and only if nothing else is ever going to use that image.  In order to know that, one would have to know where the old image came from.  In some cases, the image will have been created just for the purpose of being assigned to the `PictureBox`.  In other cases, the image might be one which is intended to be shared and/or reused.  If image was created solely for the purpose of assignment to the `PictureBox`, it should be `Dispose`d if the `PictureBox` is disposed or given another image.  If the image is supposed to be shared or reused, such conditions must not cause it to be disposed.

The proper way to resolve such issues in general would for classes which have `IDisposable` properties (like the `PictureBox`, with `Image`) to use an explicit `SetImage` method rather than having a mutable `Image` property, and for the `SetImage` method to include a parameter indicating whether the `PictureBox` should assume responsibility for disposing of it.  Calling `SetImage` or `Dispose` on the `PictureBox` should call `Dispose` on the held image if and only if the previous `SetImage` call gave it that responsibility.  Unfortunately, `PictureBox` doesn't work that way, but I would highly recommend using that as a pattern for future classes you write which hold `IDisposable` objects.

Comment: That's the only answer talking about the first part of the question, on whether to dispose an `PictureBox`'s image before assigning.

Comment: @UweKeim: I thought it was an important issue which none of the other answers touched upon.  Glad you found my answer helpful.  I suspect must of the Framework was written before people really figured out how IDisposable was going to work, and those old classes are set in stone, but there's no reason newer classes should repeat the old mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should. It implements IDisposable.
As general rule of thumb, dispose all objects that implements IDisposable. Do not leave it to GC.

Answer (score 2):

*Does bm need only to be disposed at the end, or should it be disposed before each re-creation?*

It should be disposed before each "recreation". Do not confuse an object with an object reference. "new Bitmap" creates a new object. "bm" is a reference that happens to point to that object. They are not the same. You are not "recreating" any object here - you are creating a new object, and then dropping all references to the previous object, meaning that i will be garbage collected some time in the (near) future.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I'm aware of all the concepts in your answer, but some days I have a brain freeze! Ever forgotten how to spell a short word? That's what it feels like.