# Load a PNG from Resources into a Picturebox (using Random Int Generator)

Tags: c#, image, resources, png, picturebox

I have about 600 images in resources that are formatted like this:

> poke (1).png
>
> poke (2).png
>
> poke (3).png

and so on.

Here is my code example of what im working on:

```
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.poke__1_;
```

That line of code works to load the first image like poke (1).png

But I want to be able to load a random image like this:

```
int num = rand.Next(0, 600);
pictureBox1.Image = (Image)Properties.Resources.poke__**num**_;
```

But there is no way to insert a variable right into a resource name; what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
string name;

// Generate the random name.

pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(name, Properties.Resources.Culture);
```

Also, [*if you are sure that this is the only place that sets the image*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613286/if-i-replace-an-image-in-a-picturebox-control-should-i-dispose-the-original-ima/11640576#11640576), to improve memory performance, you might want to dispose the old image:

```
using (pictureBox1.Image)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(name, Properties.Resources.Culture);
}
```

Here you have to use the *original* file name, `poke ({0}).png`, not the static property name in which [characters that are invalid in a c# property name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28VS.71%29.aspx) are replaced with an underscore.

Of course, you lose the compile-time type check you get when fetching the image from the static resource manager property.

**Update**

If you don't want to hardcode precise number of image properties, you can use reflection and query for all image-valued static properties in `Properties.Resources` whose name matches a pattern, like so:

```
public static class ResourceHelper
{
    public static PropertyInfo [] GetStaticPropertiesOfType<TValue>(Type type)
    {
        return type
          .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
          .Where(p => typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && p.GetGetMethod(true) != null)
          .ToArray();
    }
}
```

And then later, in your class:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"^poke__\d+_$");
        var propertyDictionary = ResourceHelper.GetStaticPropertiesOfType<Image>(typeof(Properties.Resources)).Where(p => regex.IsMatch(p.Name)).ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
        foreach (var property in propertyDictionary.Values)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = (Image)property.GetValue(null, null);
        }
```

Here you should use the mangled name `poke__{0}_` in which invalid property characters have been replaced.

Comment: int num = 1;
String name = "poke__" + num + "_";

and then your long line, nothing happens, the image doesn't load

Comment: @Will - make sure you actually have that named resource; if you do, `Properties.Resources.poke__1_` will exist as a static property.

Comment: @Will - answer updated.  Can't reproduce your problem though.