# .NET Winforms C# app crashes due to garbage collection affecting unmanaged library

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I have a .net C# application which uses some Chart and PictureBox controls which (albeit quite rarely) spontaneously closes.  My global exception handler isn't triggered - the app just vanishes.

The following is from the Application event log (three separate events):

```
Application: MyApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods+Gdip.GdipDrawImageRectI(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image, System.Drawing.Rectangle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs, Int16)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 14.9.8764.31123, time stamp: 0x659050b3
Faulting module name: gdiplus.dll, version: 10.0.19041.3636, time stamp: 0xb8405853
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000024f80
Faulting process id: 0x2cd4
Faulting application start time: 0x01da3d633ffe83fc
Faulting application path: C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.19041.3636_none_91a19322cc8a92a3\gdiplus.dll
Report Id: b44802f6-cb81-4188-89a2-6236e1ff5a37
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 14.9.8764.31123, time stamp: 0x659050b3
Faulting module name: gdiplus.dll, version: 10.0.19041.3636, time stamp: 0xb8405853
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x0000000000024f80
Faulting process id: 0x2cd4
Faulting application start time: 0x01da3d633ffe83fc
Faulting application path: C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.19041.3636_none_91a19322cc8a92a3\gdiplus.dll
Report Id: c5b44473-b9e4-4555-a8cf-42f32959cbb5
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

It seems to be faulting outside my code. When trying to trace the issue, I came across this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup?redirectedfrom=MSDN

... but it seems to me that is talking about initialising the GDI+ engine if you're running it from within a dll (which I'm not - this is an exe).  Plus, it only crashes rarely (and all the charts etc work fine otherwise), but I imagine if I were failing to initialise GDI+ properly it wouldn't work at all.

Should I be initialising GDI+ in my Form_Load anyway? ... or is there some other reason why the app is throwing an exception and exiting please?

Any help gratefully received.

EDIT: to include some further information. I'm using the WordCloud library by Brian Cullen on Nuget, which is called as follows:

```
var wc = new WordCloudGen(new_width, new_height);

Image wordcloud_generated_image = wc.Draw(database_wordcloud_words, database_wordcloud_frequencies);

database_results_table.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
      wordcloud_image.Image = wordcloud_generated_image;
...
```

It's multi-threaded (ie. the wordcloud is generated in the background, and I don't want it to interfere with the user's ability to interact elsewhere on the form).  I think for present purposes the detail can be sidestepped.  If, for the sake of the argument, we assume that the WordCloud library can in some circumstances return a malformed image, how can I stop the error in GDI+.  The whole block of code is wrapped in a try/catch (and there's a global exception handler too), but it's not trapping this one.

EDIT 2:

Having implemented a custom PictureBox class and enabling corrupted state exception handling, I'm able to trap the error:

```
UnhandledExceptionEventArgs
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDrawImageRectI(HandleRef graphics, HandleRef image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle rect)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at Timesheet_Writer.ErrorManagedPictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) in D:\Develop\Visual C# 2017\MyApp.cs:line 39
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

It seems to do it after the app has been minimised and left for a while, and then the user restores the window.  I do have a feeling it's something to do with the image being garbage collected, notwithstanding it's actually still in use.

I read this with interest:  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/246372/Premature-NET-garbage-collection-or-Dude-wheres-my

I'll see if explicitly managing garbage collection via KeepAlive can be made to work.

Comment: The issue is when an `Image` is being drawn in a `PictureBox`. If you're not handling the `Paint` event yourself, which doesn't appear to be the issue, then it must be an issue with an `Image` that you have specifically assigned to the `Image` property. What images are you loading into `PictureBoxes` and how? Do these crashes occur on when the same image is displayed each time or different images? Try the same image(s) in a separate test app and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  The problem seems to have started since using the WordCloud library on nuget by Brian Cullen:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/WordCloud.  I'll add some further info to the question.

Comment: I don't think the multithreading should be an issue but I would test it out using a single thread and see whether the same issue arises.

Comment: Thanks.  Updating the Image takes place on the UI thread, so it's single threaded in that context.  In practice, other than for testing purposes, it wouldn't be possible to put the wordcloud generation on the UI thread - it would block it for 3-5 seconds.

Comment: I think it's worth doing everything on the UI thread as a test to see whether the same issue arises. If it does, you can forget about multithreading as a potential cause. With that eliminated, you can focus on other potential causes. My next guess would be an `Image` created from a `Stream` that has been closed. Sometimes GDI+ will try to read more data from the source stream when the `Image` is drawn and that will fail if the stream is closed. Not sure whether that generates a specific error message though.

Comment: Is the `PictureBox` control your own? It looks like it. In that case, it may also be worth creating a custom control and overriding the `OnPaint` method, just so you can catch an exception thrown in the base method and see if you can get any more specific information about what happened and when.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a feeling this might be due to garbage collection (i.e. the image has been disposed of for some reason when it tries to render).  I think I should be disposing of the image before updating it each time.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613286/if-i-replace-an-image-in-a-picturebox-control-should-i-dispose-the-original-ima

Comment: I think trapping those types of exceptions also need special treatment.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956163/gracefully-handling-corrupted-state-exceptions

Comment: I've also, as suggested, created my own PictureBox class so I can better monitor what's going on and hopefully catch the exception/handle it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this.

I don't think that the garbage collection is actually destroying the object; rather, it can *move* objects more than 85KB in memory to optimise them (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap).  If this happens between managed and unmanaged code, the unmanaged code isn't aware it's moved, has the old pointer, and tries to read from memory space which is actually no longer associated with the Image in the PictureBox - hence the access violation.

I created my own PictureBox class and added code to "pin" the Image object in the garbage collector so it doesn't get moved.  Since I did that, I haven't been getting the exception.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MemoryManagedPictureBox : System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    {    
        public volatile Boolean exception_has_occurred = false;
        GCHandle memory_lock;

        ~MemoryManagedPictureBox()
        {
            if (this.Image != null)
            {
                this.Image.Dispose();
                memory_lock.Free();   
            }
        }

        public void set_image(ref Image im)
        {
            if ( this.Image != null )
            {
                this.Image.Dispose();
                memory_lock.Free();
            }    
            this.Image = im;    
            memory_lock = GCHandle.Alloc(this.Image, GCHandleType.Normal);    
        }

        public void clear_image()
        {
            if (this.Image != null)
            {
                this.Image.Dispose();
                this.Image = null;
                memory_lock.Free();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnPaint(e);                    
                exception_has_occurred = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                exception_has_occurred = true;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```